# I've inserted records in database manually but sql queries don't read any data in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I've inserted data manually in my local database I mean I've opened the database and inserted new records no code used

Then when I try to login or retrieve any data through a select query nothing retrieved but when I insert data from forms I can retrieve it can someone explain why?

I am using laravel 5.7

Comment: You are probably manually inserting into the wrong database. Do you have multiple environments? like staging, local, production?

Comment: I don't have multiple environments

Comment: probably you have autocommit set to false, and you are not doing commit after inserting records